# While sliding my finger over a button or object, the object acts as if it were getting pushed?

Tags: java, android

[image]

I tried to explain my issue through image, what i am looking for.

I tried

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch (action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        return true;
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
        // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
        // "of current screen element");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

I worked on `ACTION_DOWN` & `ACTION_MOVE` but didn't find what I am looking for

Comment: try to use click listener instead of the motion detector.

Comment: i tried onclick listner & ontouch listner it didn't worked

Comment: it should work. May be you setting onclick listener in wrong way. post the code of onclick listener.